# Nested for loops, is there a better way?

Tags: javascript, performance, for-loop

I need to remove empty attributes from objects stored in an array, without touching the original array.

here is my code:

```
// first I create a copy of the array
parsedShapes = [];
  for (var i in shapes) {
    parsedShapes.push(shapes[i]);
}
// then for each objects in the new array, I delete all the empty attributes.
for (var i in parsedShapes) {
  var objects = parsedShapes[i];
  for (var j in objects) {
    if (objects[j] === "") {
      delete objects[j];
    }
  }
}
```

This code works, but I wanted to know if there was a better way to handle this operation.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `.map()` and `.forEach()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can not change the value of 'shapes', I would try something like this:

```
var parsedShapes = shapes.map(function(item){
    var obj = {};
    for(var i in item){
        if(item[i] || (item[i]===false || item[i]===0)){ obj[i] = item[i]; }
    }
    return obj
});
```

This way you only have to do one cycle through 'shapes' instead of having to iterate through 'shapes' to create 'parsedShapes' then iterate through 'parsedShapes' to weedout the blanks.

```
if(item[i] || (item[i]===false || item[i]===0)){ obj[i] = item[i]; }
```

This will weed out anything of of the values 'null' or "". I am assuming that something with the value '0' or 'false' is not considered "empty".

**Note** filter() only works one arrays. So, if the items in the the collection are objects, then using filter() wont work.

Answer (score 1):

To create a copy of an array, just do this:

```
var newArray = oldArray.slice(0);
```

That aside, I can't really think of any simpler way to filter out empty values, other than just not having them there in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, I can remove a loop at least

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably do this with a `filter` function, like:

```
var filtered = object_filter(parsedShaped, function (key, shape) {
    return shape !== "";
});
```

Where filter is something like:

```
function object_filter(array) {
    var result = {};
    object_map(object, function (key, value) {
        if (filter_function(key, value)) {
            result[key] = value;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Most framework will have a function like this. If not, write your own :)